# How to add items from an SQL query to a TListView

Tags: delphi, tlist

I want to add items from a query into a TListView using a for loop. But I get an error saying 'Too many actual parameters' from the ListViewShifts.Items.Add() line. What is the correct way of adding to the list from a query?

```
  Qry := TFDQuery.Create(DBConnection);
  Qry.Connection := DBConnection;
  Qry.SQL.Text := 'SELECT Count(10) FROM Bookings WHERE NurseNo=:nurseID;';
  Qry.Params.ParamByName('nurseID').AsInteger := NurseID;
  Qry.Active := True;

  //Fill the list view with the shifts that have the nurses ID
  for Count := 0 to 10 do
  begin
    ListViewShifts.Items.Add(Qry.Fields[Count].AsString);
  end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to consider the following:

- If your `ListViewShifts` variable is `TListView`, method `ListViewShifts.Items.Add` doesn't expect parameters. This is the reason for `Too many actual parameters` error.
- SQL statement `SELECT Count(10) FROM Bookings WHERE NurseNo=:nurseID;` will return result set with only one column.
- If you want to get the first 10 rows, then probably your statement should be: `SELECT TOP(10) FROM Bookings WHERE NurseNo=:nurseID;`
- Use `First`, `Eof` and `Next` dataset methods to fetch records from your result set.

Next basic example shows how to add 10 items in your `TListView`:

```
procedure TMainForm.btnGet(Sender: TObject);
var
   li: TListItem;
begin

   Qry := TFDQuery.Create(DBConnection);
   Qry.Connection := DBConnection;
   Qry.SQL.Text := 'SELECT TOP(10) FROM Bookings WHERE NurseNo=:nurseID;';
   Qry.Params.ParamByName('nurseID').AsInteger := NurseID;
   Qry.Active := True;

   Qry.First; 
   for Count := 1 to 10 do
   begin
      Qry.Next;
      li := ListViewShifts.Items.Add;
      li.Caption := Qry.Fields[0].AsString;
   end;
   (*
   Qry.First;
   while not Qry.Eof do begin
      li := ListViewShifts.Items.Add;
      li.Caption := Qry.Fields[0].AsString;
      Qry.Next;
   end;
   *)
end;
```

Comment: This works great, but is it possible to text from multiple columns for each item? EDIT: I've done it this way `Item.Text := Qry.Fields[9].AsString + ' ' + Qry.Fields[6].AsString;` which works but seems a bit sloppy if I want to use a lot of different columns.

Comment: @WiliamCardoso You may try to use `TListItem.SubItems` to add text that appears in the additional columns when the `ViewStyle` property is `vsReport`.

Comment: I would suggest not hard coding 10 in the for loop in case there are fewer than 10 rows returned by the query.

Comment: @Zhorov I probably should've added, I'm doing this for android using FireMonkey, I don't think `TListItem` has a `.SubItems` property on FMX. Any way to do that via FMX?

Comment: @WiliamCardoso I don't know, probably it can be done, but I have no experience with FireMonkey.

Answer (score 1):

```
   VAR
   SY1:INTEGER;
   mydata:string;
   begin
   mydata:='mydatabasename';
   qry_tables.Close;
   qry_tables.SQL.Clear;
   qry_tables.SQL.text:= 'SELECT TABLE_NAME NAME FROM information_schema.TABLES       WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '+QuotedStr(mydata);
   qry_tables.Open;

   ListViewShifts.Clear;
   for SY1 := 1 to qry_tables.RecordCount do
    begin
     ListViewShifts.Items.Add(qry_tables.FieldByName('NAME').TEXT);
     qry_tables.NEXT;
    end;
```

i used mysql